# React is not re-rendering on state and props change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, mouseevent, react-props

I am trying to create a very simple drawing in React.js. Actually, I am just converting the Vanilla JS code I created into React app. [You can see the original code here on FiddleJS.](https://jsfiddle.net/60kwvqt9/)

Everything seems to work, but the component which is rendering points is not re-rendering on props change. However, its props are changing (I checked it in react-dev-tools). I am using custom event listeners, could that be the cause of the error?

```
import React, { useEffect, useState} from "react";

const addPoint = ({points, setPoints}) => (event) => {
    const newPts = points;
    newPts.push([event.pageX, event.pageY]);
    setPoints(newPts);
};

const handleMouseDown = (pts) => (event) => {
 console.log(pts.points);
  document
    .getElementById("drawing")!
    .addEventListener("mousemove", handleMouseMove(pts));
};

const handleMouseUp = (pts) => (event) => {
  document
    .getElementById("drawing")!
    .removeEventListener("mousemove", handleMouseMove(pts));
};

const handleMouseMove = (pts) => (event) => {
  addPoint(pts) (event);
};

// Does not re-render when the props change
function RenderPoints(props) {
    return (
        <svg id="drawing" height="400" width="450">
        <g id="points" stroke="black" strokeWidth="3" fill="black">
          {props.points.map((point, index) => {
            return <circle cx={point[0]} cy={point[1]} r="3" key={index}/>;
          })}
        </g>
      </svg>
    );
}

export default function Contact() {
  useEffect(() => {
    document
      .getElementById("drawing")!
      .addEventListener("mousedown", handleMouseDown({points, setPoints}));
    document
      .getElementById("drawing")!
      .addEventListener("mouseup", handleMouseUp({points, setPoints}));
    return () => {
      document
        .getElementById("drawing")!
        .removeEventListener("mousedown", handleMouseDown({points, setPoints}));
      document
        .getElementById("drawing")!
        .removeEventListener("mouseup", handleMouseUp({points, setPoints}));
    };
  });
  const [points, setPoints] = useState([[100, 100]]);
  return (
    <>
      <div>Draw</div>
      <RenderPoints points={points} />
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Are you sure this `[[100, 100]]` is right? Can you try just with `[100, 100]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `addPoints` function, you are pushing another element into the same `points` array. React does a shallow compare when comparing arrays and objects, which means it does not dive into whether the array contents have changed - it just checks if the state variable (here, `points`) is a reference to the same array or a different one.

`Array.prototype.push` does not create a new array, it just pushes a new element into the same array. So even though the contents of `points` change, `points` is still the same array. This is why React does not rerender your component.

To fix this, instead of pushing into the same array, do this:

```js
const newPts = [...points, [event.pageX, event.pageY]]
```

This would create a new array each time, so React would rerender your component now.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation!

Comment: thankyou finally found satisfying answer.

Comment: @Eldrax, Thank you! I save my day too